# Is there a way I could plot t = 300, 350, 450, and 500 lines in one graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, ecdf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmmzS.png)I wanted to plot multiple lines in one graph but I couldn't figure out which code to use. Also, is there a way I could assign colors to each of the lines? Just new to Rstudio and was assigned to pick up someones work so I've been doing a lot of trial and error but I haven't been lucky for the past few days. Hope someone could help me with this! Thank you so much

```r
ecdf.shift <- function(OUR_threshold, des_cap = 40, nint = 10000){

  #create some empty vectors for later use in the loop

  ecdf_med = c() 
  ecdf_obs = c()

  for (i in 1:length(OUR_threshold)){

    # filter out the OUR threshold data, then select only the capture column and create a ecdf function

    ecdf_fun <- HRP_rESS_no %>% 
      filter(ESS > OUR_threshold[i]) %>%
      .$TSS_con %>%
      ecdf()

    # extract the ecdf data and put in tibble dataframe, then create a linear interpolation of the curve. 

    ecdf_data <- tibble(TSS_con = environment(ecdf_fun)$x, prob = environment(ecdf_fun)$y)
    ecdf_interpol <- approx(x = ecdf_data$TSS_con, y = ecdf_data$prob, n = nint)

    # find the vector numbers in x which correspond with the desired capture. Then find correlate the vectornumbers with probability numbers in the y vectors. Take the median value in case multiple hits. Put this number in a vector with designed vectornumber as ditacted by the loopnumber i. 



    ecdf_med[i] <- median(ecdf_interpol$y[(round(ecdf_interpol$x,1) == des_cap)])



    # calculate the number of observations when the filtering takes place. 

    ecdf_obs[i] <- HRP_rESS_no %>% 
      filter(ESS > OUR_threshold[i]) %>%
      .$TSS_con %>%
      length()

    # Flush the ecdf data. The ecdf is encoded as a function with global paramaters, so you want to reset them everytime the loop is done to avoid pesky bugs to appear. 

    rm(ecdf_data)
  }

  #create a tibble dataframe with all the loop data. 

  ecdf_out <- tibble(OUR_ratio_cutoff = OUR_threshold, prob = (ecdf_med)*100, nobs = ecdf_obs)



  return(ecdf_out)

}

ratio_threshold <- seq(0,115, by = 5)
t = ecdf_MLSS_target <- 400 %>% 
 ecdf.shift(ratio_threshold, .) %>% 
  filter(nobs > 2) %>%
  ggplot(aes( x = OUR_ratio_cutoff, y = prob)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_bw(base_size = 12) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100), 
                     breaks = seq(0,300, by = 5), 
                     expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,120), 
                     breaks = seq(0,110, by = 10), 
                     expand = c(0,0)) +
  labs(x = "ESS mg TSS/L",
       y = "Probability of contactor MLSS > 400 mg TSS/L ")




plot(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to loop over your different t values first and bring the resulting data frames into one big data frame, and use this for your plot. Your code is not fully reproducible (it requires data that we do not have, i.e. `HRP_rESS_no`). So I have stripped down the function to the core - creating a data frame which makes different "lines" depending on your t value. I just used it as slope.

I hope the idea is clear.

```r
library(tidyverse)

ecdf.shift <- function(OUR_threshold, t) {
  data.frame(x = OUR_threshold, y = t * OUR_threshold)
}

ratio_threshold <- seq(0, 115, by = 5)

t_df <-
  map(1:5, function(t) ecdf.shift(ratio_threshold, t)) %>%
  bind_rows(, .id = "t")

ggplot(t_df, aes(x, y, color = t)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>